# force line break in a html table after of columns

Tags: html, css

I want to have just 4 columns per `row` in my `table`, how can i force a line break in table using `css` ?
please check what i'v tried in the link below -

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;overflow-wrap: break-word;width:25%"></td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;overflow-wrap: break-word;width:25%"></td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;overflow-wrap: break-word;width:25%"></td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;overflow-wrap: break-word;width:25%"></td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;overflow-wrap: break-word;width:25%"></td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

LINK - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sihamxxi/9L1xoy3u/)

Comment: only add 4 columns, you cannot restruct table with CSS, the purpose of CSS is to style

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do it using Bootstrap :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;"><table>...</table></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;"><table>...</table></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;"><table>...</table></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavenderblush;"><table>...</table></div>
</div>
```